# Must Declare Scalar Variable

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string ssr;
        SqlConnection scr = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=USER-PC\MSSQL;Initial Catalog=Highscore;Integrated Security=True");
        scr.Open();
        ssr = "Select Nume,Scor,DataInitiala,DataRecenta FROM Users where DataInitiala between @Param and @Param1 ";
        SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(ssr, scr);
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Param", from.Text);
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Param1", to.Text);
        SqlDataAdapter adapter1 = new SqlDataAdapter(ssr, scr);
        DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
        adapter1.Fill(ds1);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds1.Tables[0];
        dataGridView1.Refresh();  


    }
```

What am I missing here?I have the error Must Declare scalar variable @Param

Comment: what is `from.Text`'s value?

Comment: the value is entered by the user in the app(it is a date)

Comment: If you're dealing with date/time/timestamps, [you don't want to use `BETWEEN`](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common).  Also, you should be converting the parameters to the proper type before inclusion in the query anyways, don't just assume the text values are correct.  This doesn't necessarily solve your problem, though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you declaring Parameters variable in **cmd2** but you are calling **ssr** in **adapter1**.

Try this

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string ssr;
        SqlConnection scr = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=USER-PC\MSSQL;Initial Catalog=Highscore;Integrated Security=True");
        scr.Open();
        ssr = "Select Nume,Scor,DataInitiala,DataRecenta FROM Users where DataInitiala between @Param and @Param1 ";
        SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(ssr, scr);
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Param", from.Text);
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Param1", to.Text);
        SqlDataAdapter adapter1 = new SqlDataAdapter();
        adapter1.SelectCommand = cmd2;
        DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
        adapter1.Fill(ds1);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds1.Tables[0];
        dataGridView1.Refresh();         
    }
```

Comment: I got 2 errors on new SqlDataAdapter(cmd2,scr) : 1.The best overloaded method match for 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlAdapter.SqlDataAdapter(string,system.data.sqlClient.SqlConnection) has some invalid arguments. 2Argument1:cannot convert from SystemData.SqlClient.SqlCommand to string

Answer (score 0):

please see the below query:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string ssr;
        SqlConnection scr = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=USER-PC\MSSQL;Initial Catalog=Highscore;Integrated Security=True");
        scr.Open();
        ssr = "Select Nume,Scor,DataInitiala,DataRecenta FROM Users where DataInitiala between @Param and @Param1 ";
        SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(ssr, scr);
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Param", from.Text);
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Param1", to.Text);
        SqlDataAdapter adapter1 = new SqlDataAdapter();
        adapter1.SelectCommand = cmd2;
        DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
        adapter1.Fill(ds1);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds1.Tables[0];
        dataGridView1.Refresh();         
    }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.